# Google Tag Manager set field value to one of two variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are using Google Tag Manager. It is sending a custom dimension to Google Analytics with a value of {{fc-isSubscribedSession}} variable

[image]

The fc-isSubscribedSession variable is a DOM variable that is taken from the data-is-subscribed-session attribute on the page body.

We are migrating our platform. The old user interface makes use of the  tag and the data-is-subscribed-session attribute. The new user interface is more like SPA so we are using the data layer to push the data to GTM like

```
window.dataLayer.push({
    'newInterfaceIsSubscribedSession': current_user.is_subscribed?
  });
```

(above is a fragment that is close enough to the real call)

Now the problem is that we must fill the dimension from fc-isSubscribedSession or from newInterfaceIsSubscribedSession.

Do you know if there is a way to fill a dimension from one of two values?

Something like
{{fc-isSusbscribedSession}} or {{newInterfaceIsSubscribedSession}}

Comment: From the  top of my head, create a DOM variable for {{fc-isSusbscribedSession}} and use the "format value" fields at the bottom to fill in the value of DOM variable {{newInterfaceIsSubscribedSession}} if {{fc-isSusbscribedSession}}  is null (or undefined, I always forget what this returns when the element is not present).

Comment: Cannot find a way to do this. The format value is only  Change Case to...
 Convert null to...
 Convert undefined to...
 Convert true to...
 Convert false to...

Comment: Convert null to allows you to use variables. So if one variable returns null, you can use another variable as the value.

Comment: Genius. It is "convert undefined to" that did the job, but it is genius. Thanks.